# VHDL: How to convert Bit_Vector to Std_Logic_Vector?

Tags: vhdl

I want to move data from a "**Bit_vector**" to "**Std_logic_Vector**". For that, I want to convert Bit_Vector into Std_Logic_Vector. Please help me for the same.

Comment: Is Electrical Engineering the right place to ask simple type conversion questions, which could be answered by a beginners text book or e-book on VHDL?

Comment: I tried text book, then Google. then only I tried here. May be for you it will be simple. But for me its big. May be my IQ is below average. @Paebbels

Comment: Every basic VHDL book should cover the topic of type conversions. Thats no question of programing skills or 'IQ'.

Comment: The [Supplemental Material](http://standards.ieee.org/downloads/1076/1076-2008/) download contains the source for all the standard packages. In package std_logic_1164 you'll find the declaration `function To_StdLogicVector  (b : BIT_VECTOR) return STD_LOGIC_VECTOR;`. Searching these package sources make a great authoritative alternative to a second hand answer when trying to learn how things work. Interogative google searches (*how to convert bit_vector to std_logic_vector in vhdl*) usually point you to an answer, likely where Sarrk found it in this case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try [Srinivasan Venkataramanan's solution](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.vhdl/OxgjdpZDOxU)

> Use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164 package's function To_StdLogicVector  to do this:
>
> FUNCTION To_StdLogicVector  ( b : BIT_VECTOR        ) RETURN
>   std_logic_vector;

Comment: I tried its working... To make it simple S<=to_stdlogicvector(b);

Comment: It's not so much Srini's solution as it is knowledge of the package std_logic_1164. See the [Supplemental Material](http://standards.ieee.org/downloads/1076/1076-2008/) download for IEEE Std 1076-2008. The package sources can be searched and you can learn how things work in VHDL from them.